# POWER BI: Values appear in Transform Data but not in the visualization

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table `PRODUCTS` in Power BI that has a column named `Product_Group`.
When I go to transform data I can see all the Product groups. (DirectQuery connection, it is refreshed and the data that I see is the same as in the database)

I Close and Apply, create a table and put only the `Product_Group` as a column and one specific product group does not show up.

After test and investigation, I've performed so many tests to see if I can find out why this is happening.

- Checked if there was any filter applied in the Transform Data and also in the report page.
- Refreshed the data.
- Cleared the cache.
- Changed that table from Direct Query to Import storage mode.
- Double-checked the relationships of the Data Model.
- Checked the option to show items with no data.
- I even created a new pbix file, connected only to that table and the behaviour was the same
- When I add another column which I call `Dataset` (which basically has a string that says from which area of the business the data came from), that field that I want to see in the `Product_Group` shows up -> so I guess that maybe granularity has a play in this? But it does not make much sense... I was expecting that when putting a column in a table, that it would list all the available values.

Any ideas of what I can try next?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally realised that the problem was in the relations between tables. You can try activate and deactivate the different relations that you have (one by one) and see if the data missing appears suddenly. If this happens, the problem might be related with this column you have last deactivate.

P.D.: You can make a relationship active or not active without deleting it by clicking Properties.

Wish it helps